# In Bipartite graph, what if we have more than two sets

Tags: graph-theory

In a bipartite graph $\hat{G}=(O,E)$, the vertex set is partitioned into two distinct sets $O=U\cup V$ and $U\cap V=\emptyset$. What if $G$ has more than two sets i.e., $U,V,D$. Does this considered Bipartite graph? is there a name for such graphs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/k-PartiteGraph.html). The general term is $k$-partite. Bipartite graphs are $2$-partite.